# Can't figure out how to make my funtion not return None in Python

Tags: python

I have a program I am trying to make which will either show all the factors of a number or say it is prime. It's a simple program but I have one main issue. Once it prints all of the factors of an inputted number, it always returns none. I have tried multiple ways to get rid of it but nothing works without screwing something else up. The code is below.

```
def mys(x):
    x = input("Enter a number: ")
    for i in range(2,x):
        r = x % i
        if r == 0:
            print(i)
print(mys(x))
```

That code is just for printing the factors but that is where the problem lies. The results I get after entering a number, in this case 20, are as follows:

```
2
4
5
10
None
```

No matter what I do, I can't get the None to not print.

Comment: You didnt add a return statment at the end of the function, so it returns none. Just dont print mys(x), call it without a print.

Comment: Make it return something other than none? Or don't print the result of calling it.

Comment: You never `return` from the function.

Comment: `print` != `return`.

Comment: Why do people downvote this question? It is a valid one.

Comment: @Selcuk I can't really see how it is a valid question, to be honest.

Comment: @SitiSchu The OP wrote some code, got some unexpected behavior. If it's a duplicate go ahead and mark it, but it conforms to the format and community guidelines.

Comment: @Selcuk I didnt downvote btw, but I guess others may have done it for the lack of research ? If you put the question title in google you get a few results that could help.

Comment: @SitiSchu I am not suggesting that it is _not_ a duplicate but downvoting is not very welcoming.

Answer (score 3):

So if you don't want the return value of `mys` (None) not printed, then don't print it:

```
mys(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

In python, a function that has no return statement always returns None.

I guess what you are trying to do is calling the mys function, and not printing it. 
Note that you should remove x parameter, because it is asked inside of the function.

```
def mys():
    x = input("Enter a number: ")
    for i in range(2,x):
        r = x % i
        if r == 0:
            print(i)
mys()
```

It would be better not to include user input and printing in your function. It would make it easier to test and to reuse:

```
def mys(x):
    result = []
    for i in range(2,x):
        r = x % i
        if r == 0:
            result.append(i)
    return result

x = input("Enter a number: ")
print(mys(x))
```